# AES Encryption and Obfuscating IDs

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, uniqueidentifier

I was considering hashing small blocks of sensitive ID data but I require to *maintain the full uniqueness of the data blocks as a whole* once obfuscated.

So, I came up with the idea of encrypting some publicly-known input data (say, 128 bits of zeroes), and ***use the data I want to obfuscate as the key/password, then throw it away***, thus protecting the original data from ever being discovered.

I already know about hashing algorithms, but my problem is that I need to ***maintain full uniqueness*** (generally speaking a **1:1 mapping** of input to output) while still ***making it impossible to retrieve the actual input.*** A hash cannot serve this function because information is lost during the process.

**It is not necessary that the data be retrieved once "encrypted".** It is only to be used as an ID number from then on.

An actual GUID/UUID is not suitable here because I need to manually control the identifiers on a per-identifier basis. The IDs cannot be unknown or arbitrarily generated data.

---

**EDIT:** To clarify exactly **what** these identifiers are made of:

- **(unencrypted)** 64bit Time Stamp
- ID Generation Counter (one count for each filetype)
- Random Data (to make multiple encrypted keys dissimilar)
- MAC Address (or if that's not available, set top bit + random digits)
- Other PC-Specific Information (from registry)

The whole thing should add up to 192 bits, but the encrypted section's content size(s) could vary (this is by no means a final specification).

---

**Given:**

- A static IV value
- Any arbitrary 128bit key
- A static 128 bits of input

Are AES keys treated in a fashion that would result in a `1:1 key<---->output` mapping, **given the same input and IV value?**

Comment: Do you have evidence to support the idea that using the sensitive data as the key rather than the payload is more secure?

Comment: What kind of data space does your "sensitive ID data" come from? For example, if your ID data is US social security numbers, there are only a billion of those so the search space is quite small for an attacker looking to reverse your obfuscation.

Comment: Also, why can't the ID be "arbitrarily generated data"?  Why can't an incrementing number be used?

Comment: An incrementing number cannot be used by itself. The data is going to be a combination of MAC address, some other pc-specific information, randomly generated bits, and finally an incrementing counter that's based on the filetype.

I'm going for the ability to generate unique IDs that differ per file type, and per each individual file, and do not change once generated.

But I do not want the MAC address or the other PC-specific data exposed for all to see.

If I completely _THROW AWAY_ the key data after using it to encrypt something else, there shouldn't be a way to retrieve the key, correct?

Comment: Also, a time stamp is included in another external, unencrypted 64 bits.

Comment: There is certainly a 1:1 plaintext<---->output mapping. Any reason you couldn't swap the key and data fields?

Comment: Alternately, if you just use a big enough hash, you'll be retired well before the first collision occurs. ;^)

Comment: I wanted to use the protected data _as_ the key, **so that a secret key doesn't have to be kept secret!**

If the key exists somewhere, it's more vulnerable than if I encrypt known data with a key that no longer exists (lock + throw away key **VS** lock + hide key). Since I don't want the data back, who cares.

My original reasoning for using encryption rather than a hash was the uniqueness. But my actual question was whether this would actually have a 1:1 key-to-output. I've a feeling it does but I'm no cryptography expert.

Comment: @Simion32: I know this isn't the topic of your question, but I'm not sure I understand why you can't simply use incrementing numbers.  As I understand, you want to assign a unique ID to each {MAC,pc-specific,file-type,etc.} combination?  Simply assigning the next number in an incrementing sequence sounds like it fits this description.  (Incidentally, your question update mentions 192-bit data; this certainly won't give a 1:1 mapping with a 128-bit output ID!)

Comment: **The encrypted/sensitive data is only 128 bits**, and there are 64 bits of timestamp data that's **not** encrypted, adding up to 192 bits.

I can't use JUST incrementing numbers because the same code that generates IDs will be running on different machines. Only doing an incrementing counter is going to _guarantee_ clashes. This is intended to handle user-creation of a lot of resources where each file gets a unique ID (at least unique within each filetype).

Finally, getting the incrementing number from a server is not one of my design options, the program must work offline.

Comment: I see you've already given up on the idea, but wanted to add that there is a way to reconstruct the keys in your scheme, if there is predictable data in your 128-bit "key space". For every byte that can be predicted, like an ID generation counter, that carves another 8 bits off of your "key" size, making a brute force discovery of all "keys" closer and closer to within reach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. AES is, in the abstract, a family of permutations of which you select a random one with the key. It is the case that for one of those permutations(i.e. for encryption under a given AES key) you will not get collisions because permutations are bijective.

However, for two different permutations (i.e. encryption under different AES keys, which is what you have), there is no guarantee what so ever that you don't get a collision. Indeed, because of the birthday paradox, the likelihood of a collision is probably higher than you think.

If your ID's are short ( < 1024 bits) you could just do an RSA encryption of them which would give you want you want. You'd just need to forget the private key.

Comment: Well, that answers my main question... how disappointing.

I've already researched RSA, and 1024 bits is far too large (message size) since the IDs will be used in some filetypes to reference _other_ files with this same ID format. Are there **any** such asymmetric encryption algorithms that can secure exactly 128 bits without increasing the message size?

Comment: Not securely. The weakest you can safely go is 160 bit elliptic curves and that's for the key size, I think the encrypted elements would be slightly bigger than that.

Comment: I guess I'll entirely give up my hare-brained idea of encrypting it, and just use SHA-1 or SHA-2 and truncate off some of the bits, and rely on the extremely remote chances of a collision happening being basically zero. Thanks for the answer though, this helped me clear my thoughts on the matter.