# How to decrypt SSN field from DB that is encrypted using Crypt::encrypt in Laravel?

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5

I am trying to create a web service where I will be passing an ID, UserName, SSN as input parameters and retrieve all the required information of that particular user in JSON response.

I can create DB query to gather user data and filter the query result based on ID, UserName. But, SSN is encrypted using Crypt::encrypt() and then stored in the Database. Now I have to decrypt the value and match it with user entered SSN in the input parameter.

I tried using `Crypt::decrypt()` in where clause of DB query but it didn't work out. How do I decrypt the SSN in such situation?

My original query is:

```
$ssn = 123456789; 
$res = DB::table('users')
            ->where('users.ssn', '=', $ssn)
            ->select('users.ssn as SSN')
            ->get();
```

I tried to decrypt SSN from DB:

```
$res = DB::table('users')
        ->where('Crypt::decrypt(users.ssn)', '=', $ssn)
        ->select('users.ssn as SSN')
        ->get();
```

Comment: _"Now I have to decrypt the value and match it with user entered SSN in the input parameter."_ No, what you need to do is encrypt the SSN entered and match it against the encrypted SSN in your db. Otherwise you'll need a supercomputer and a whole lotta time.

Comment: @j08691 Okay, got it. Thank you for the solution. Will try this way.

Comment: I suggest using  `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead of your `crypt` class. [You should hash them, not encrypt them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037007/storing-ssns-in-a-database)

Comment: @j08691,  Crypt::encrypt() is creating a new value every time I run, so how to verify this with encrypted SSN in DB?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, SSN encryption is already done and stored in DB. So, I can't change the method now.